# I want to stop wordpress for generating thumnails

Tags: wordpress

My WordPress website is generating thumbnails for my images I want to prevent WordPress from doing that how can I achieve the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow these steps for the same :

Step 1: In Admin Panel Go to Settings -> Media.

Step 2: Now Uncheck (Crop thumbnail) If it's Checked.

Step 3: Set at Thumbnail size, Medium size, and Large size the Width and Height to

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [`remove_image_size()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_image_size/) method like so:

```
add_action( 'init', 'so_73173777_remove_image_sizes' );
function so_73173777_remove_image_sizes() {
    remove_image_size( '1200' );
    remove_image_size( 'portfolio-full' );
    remove_image_size( 'blog-medium' );
    
    /* etc ... */
}
```

For removing default WP sizes:

```
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'so_73173777_remove_core_sizes' );
// This will remove the default image sizes and the medium_large size.
function so_73173777_remove_core_sizes( $sizes ) {
    unset( $sizes['small']);
    unset( $sizes['medium']);
    unset( $sizes['large']);
    unset( $sizes['medium_large']);
    return $sizes;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider searching for these particular problems, because this took me 5 seconds to find this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-generate-thumbnails/

Comment: I want to do it for specific large size images without any plugin